# Adding vector layer to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, data, layers, vector, pdf

I am learning QGIS from scratch. Downloaded the software and data. I am following their manual uploaded in PDF format. I am stuck in the first step to add the vector layer. The layers panel show a black cross besides the layer name.

I believe it did not load the layer(S) properly. This is what I see on my screen.

[image]

Comment: right-click any of the layers and choose "zoom to layer extent" - you should see the data. the X is just a toggle to turn the layer on and off...

Comment: you can also right-click on the layer in the Layers Panel and select "Open Attribute Table" to see if there are any rows/features in your layer

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it is working properly. Try right-clicking a layer, then zoom to layer extent for you to view it on the map canvas to the right.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried by zooming into the layer extent like in ArcGIS but still the layer is not visible. I am checking other options too.

Comment: Do you see any of the layers in the map canvas? Also, can you update your question with another screenshot of exactly what you are seeing in the QGIS?

Comment: Updated the question.